# Killing a windows service

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a windows service named 'shipper' running which processes files.

In task manager, the Services tab shows the following

```
name:shipper
PID: 5000
status:running
```

In the Process tab:

```
image name: java.exe 
user: SYSTEM
```

When I execute the following:

```
taskkill /f /PID 5000
```

task manager (Services tab) shows that the service is stopped.
However, it continues to execute and process files.

Only when I end the process in task manager will the process stop.
Similarly, this will work:

```
taskkill /f /im "java.exe"
```

But of course, that kills all java processes.

What is the correct way, using `taskkill` (or another standard windows command) to kill the process using the name of the service ("shipper" in this case)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `net stop shipper` before (or instead of) `taskkill`?

Answer (score 1):

Find the processID used by your service:

`for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i  in ('sc queryex "shipper" ^|findstr PID') do echo %%i`

or try a filter `TASKKILL /F /FI "services eq shipper"`

in addition you may use the following parameter of taskkill:
`/T`

> Tree kill: terminates the specified process and any child processes which were started by it.

Comment: That gives me the correct PID, but does not solve the problem. When I use taskkill with that PID, while TaskManager says that the service has stopped, the process (java.exe) continues to run.

Comment: ok sorry. Did you try with `/T`  Tree kill: terminates the specified process  and any child processes which were started by it.

Comment: `taskkill /F /T /FI "SERVICES eq MyServiceName"`solved my problem, killing all child processes created by MyServiceName